# TrueTypeFont initialization causing Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, lwjgl, slick2d

I have been building a Java game using LWJGL. Recently I decided to stop using a bitmap font (low resolution and low flexibility) and start using Slick for displaying text. I've imported slick-util.jar into my Libraries (I am on Eclipse).

When trying to initialize a TrueTypeFont (I am using [this tutorial](http://ninjacave.com/slickutil3)), however, the code crashes. Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/opengl/GLContext
at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.renderer.ImmediateModeOGLRenderer.canTextureMirrorClamp(ImmediateModeOGLRenderer.java:408)
at org.newdawn.slick.util.BufferedImageUtil.getTexture(BufferedImageUtil.java:124)
at org.newdawn.slick.util.BufferedImageUtil.getTexture(BufferedImageUtil.java:39)
at org.newdawn.slick.TrueTypeFont.createSet(TrueTypeFont.java:237)
at org.newdawn.slick.TrueTypeFont.<init>(TrueTypeFont.java:98)
at org.newdawn.slick.TrueTypeFont.<init>(TrueTypeFont.java:112)
at StarshipArena.loop(StarshipArena.java:956)
at StarshipArena.run(StarshipArena.java:225)
at StarshipArena.main(StarshipArena.java:1470)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 9 more
```

Other posts have suggested that one must put initialization of TrueTypeFont behind glInit; I have done that but am unsure if there are other OpenGL commands that need to be run to establish GLContext or something.

Any help is appreciated; thanks.

Comment: Oh.......What is the best solution to render text in LWJGL 3?

Comment: I agree; it's a bit too complex for me to understand. Is there any ready-to-use library for text (a Slick equivalent for LWJGL 3) that you know of?